# How to properly setup ResourceBundle and ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader, resourcebundle

I want to pass the correct ResourceBundle to my Jasper report, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. This is my code so far:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("Bundle.properties").getFile()); 
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()}; 
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls); 
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundle", locale, loader);
```

But this gives me the

`java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name bundle, locale XX_XX`

error :(

My bundle file are here:

```
src/main/resources/Bundle.properties
src/main/resources/bundle_en.properties
src/main/resources/bundle_de.properties
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you should use `classLoader`, not `loader`. I'm guessing `loader` is just a failed workaround, so I suggest you remove it.

Secondly, the fallback bundle file should probably be called `bundle.properties`, not `Bundle.properties`.